# I want to override value of theme's inbuilt SCSS variable in my SCSS file based on color set(Theme color) inside @mixin

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, sass

I have a global SCSS variable i.e. **$accent : #3a99d5;** and I want to override this variable based on my color selection inside @mixin, Please refer below code for more clarity.

Using below code I'm able to switch color of "**.main-header** " based on class name "green" or "orange " appending in body(refer HTML block) but unable to override **$accent** which is primary variable that controls all primary color of theme.

I'm not sure about my code. Please help me in fixing this and thanks in advance.

> /*=====SCSS======*/

```
$accent:#3a99d5; /*global variable*/

$themes: ( green: #90c140, orange: #bf5700 ); /*color set*/

@mixin theme($name,$color) {

    @if $name == green {
        $accent: #90c140 !global;
    }
    @else {
        $accent: #bf5700 !global;
    }

    .#{$name} {
        .main-header {
           background: $color;
           }
       }
}


@each $key, $value in $themes {
    @include theme($key, $value);
}
```

> /*====HTML=====*/

```
    <body class="green"> /*how I'm using color class from my SCSS*/
<div class"main-header">

</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting green in quote marks, i.e. a string?

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: Your code works for me and the global variable gets overwritten. What is your desired CSS output?

Comment: @Marvin, can you share code reference on jsfiddle or codepen if possible?

Comment: I just pasted your code on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) and added `.class { color: $accent };` to the beginning of the mixin for checking the value of the global variable. You could also add this to the very end of your code to see if the global variable has changed.

Comment: I got the problem dude, thanks for your hint ;-)